# Start app from PowerShell executing in custom runspace, keep app running, finish script?

Tags: powershell

I have a custom PowerShell runspace from which I execute a script (simplified):

```
Pipeline pipeline = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline(@"c:\temp\Myscript.ps1");
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeLine.Invoke();
```

In the script I do:

```
# c:\temp\MyScript.ps1
notepad.exe
```

Now the `Invoke()` returns when notepad is closed.

Is there a way to start an app, keep the app running but finishing the script code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the script you can do

```
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start("notepad.exe")
```